# Running p2.process.artifacts in Jenkins

Tags: eclipse, ant, equinox, eclipse-pde, p2

I read the SO post [*Running P2 Ant tasks outside Eclipse*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2327393/running-p2-ant-tasks-outside-eclipse), which was a great help. I am trying to call p2.process.artifacts, however I am not sure what arguments should I pass to java task call. What should value for application argument be and how can I pass augment for jar signing (p2.process.arifacts:sign) to this call which is nested in p2.process.artifacts element?

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run with Java calling Eclipse's AntRunner to run an ant script (eg., build.xml) containing the  task, you could do it like this:

```
  java -cp /path/to/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_*.jar \
      org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main -consoleLog -nosplash -data /tmp \
      -application org.eclipse.ant.core.antRunner -f build.xml
```

Then build.xml would be something like:

```
<project default="pack">
  <target name="pack">
    <property name="workDir" value="${basedir}/somerepofolder/"/>
    <p2.process.artifacts pack="true" repositoryPath="file:${workDir}" />
  </target>
</project>
```