# How to construct an Eclipse instance for standalone (CI) execution?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-pde, p2

I need to use the p2 publishing tools from a headless build, and hence need, AFAICT, to assemble an Eclipse execution environment for that.  I'm basing this on [Running p2.process.artifacts in Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12327748/running-p2-process-artifacts-in-jenkins), [Running P2 Ant tasks outside Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2327393/running-p2-ant-tasks-outside-eclipse), and the related documentation.

But I can't find how to assemble the directory structure necessary to start Eclipse from.  For instance, if I stupidly just run the launcher in any old directory as in:

```
java -jar <targetProductFolder>/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_*.jar
 -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.UpdateSitePublisher ...
```

it won't run without access to all the required plugins, probably some config files, etc.  How should these be assembled?

The context is a build environment, where all source and tooling (including whatever is needed for headless Eclipse) is checked out of repositories prior to the build.

Comment: Simplest is to just use a full Eclipse install, just unzipping an Eclipse download should be enough.

Comment: @greg-449 - because of the way our repositories are set up, and our slow network, adding a 200MB+ zip file to our build dependencies will cause a fair amount of ire among my colleagues.

Comment: You don't need a 200MB+ Eclipse distro to do this. The base platform is 60MB and that's all that you need. Find downloads labeled eclipse-platform-* on this page: http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/R-4.3.2-201402211700/

Comment: @KonstantinKomissarchik - Thanks, but we also have developers and build machines on a few different operating systems - linux and win64, at a minimum.  So I'm really looking/hoping for a Java-centric, platform-independent assembly mechanism.  Maybe Buckminster, but I've not explored it yet.